# Updating Dynamic Column, SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select 
    Case 
       When VacationsAvailed = 'Yes' 
          Then Sum(Convert(int, dbo.RemainingDays(a.DutyFrom, a.DutyTo,  a.VacationsAvailed))) over (order by a.Sno)
    End [RemainingDays] 
from 
    OLVA a
```

This query results in:

```
RemainingDays
---------------
     2
     6
    NULL
     17
    NULL
    NULL
    NULL
     31
```

What I want to do is: when `RemainingDays` exceeds 30, then last value of  `RemainingDays = RemainingDays - 30`, and all the previous rows of RemainingDays = 0;

[image: Description and derivation of RemainingDays is define in the attached image]

Comment: SQL tables are "un-ordered" but the concept of "previous rows" requires that there is an order. What defines "previous rows"? (how are the rows to be ordered?) Can you please provide **sample data** (as text see https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/  please don't use images of data)

Comment: As u can see 31 is the last row of RemainingDays, it should be override as 31-30 = 1 and all the above rows of RemainingDays                                                       
  ( 2
     6
    NULL
     17
    NULL
    NULL
    NULL)   should be updated as 0

Comment: Which DB are you using? Update that in tags.

Comment: Which db you are using? With clause may help your problem

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select   FooSno,EmpNo,DutyFrom,DutyTo, DutyPeriod,LE_EL
   , LE_Bal,LeaveFrom,LeaveTo,LeavesTaken
   , VacationsAvailed,Nature,Remarks, LE_Bal - LeavesTaken [Balance]
   , RemainingDays 
from 
(
Select *,
Case 
when FooSno = 1 then LE_EL
when FooSno > 1 then
((SUM(Convert(int,LE_EL)) OVER (Order By FooSno)) - ((SUM(LeavesTaken) Over (Order By FooSno) - LeavesTaken)))
end [LE_Bal]
from
(
select a.EmpNo,a.Sno,a.DutyFrom,a.DutyTo,dbo.GetDateDifference(a.DutyFrom,a.DutyTo) [DutyPeriod],
dbo.GetEarnedLeaves(a.DutyFrom,a.DutyTo,VacationsAvailed) [LE_EL],
ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By a.EmpNo) [FooSno],
a.LeaveFrom,a.LeaveTo,
Case when DateDiff(dd,a.LeaveFrom,a.LeaveTo) <> 0 then (DateDiff(dd,a.LeaveFrom,a.LeaveTo)+1) 
else DateDiff(dd,a.LeaveFrom,a.LeaveTo) end [LeavesTaken],
a.VacationsAvailed,a.Nature,a.Remarks,
ISNULL(Case 
when a.VacationsAvailed = 'Yes' then
SUM(Convert(int,dbo.RemainingDays(a.DutyFrom,a.DutyTo,a.VacationsAvailed))) over (order by a.Sno)
end,0)
[RemainingDays]
from OLVA a
)y
)z
where EmpNo = (1)
order by Sno
```

This query derives this Result :-

```
+--------+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+
| FooSno | EmpNo |  DutyFrom  |   DutyTo   | DutyPeriod  | LE_EL | LE_Bal | LeaveFrom  |  LeaveTo   | LeavesTaken | VacationsAvailed | Nature | Remarks | Balance | RemainingDays |
+--------+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+
|      1 |     1 | 1997-03-31 | 2004-07-01 | 7 - 3 - 2   |    87 |     87 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | Yes              |        |         |      87 |             2 |
|      2 |     1 | 2006-01-28 | 2006-12-31 | 0 - 11 - 4  |    11 |     98 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | Yes              |        |         |      98 |             6 |
|      3 |     1 | 2007-01-01 | 2012-03-23 | 5 - 2 - 23  |   250 |    348 | 2012-03-24 | 2012-04-01 |           9 | No               |        |         |     339 |             0 |
|      4 |     1 | 2012-04-02 | 2012-04-12 | 0 - 0 - 11  |     0 |    339 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | Yes              |        |         |     339 |            17 |
|      5 |     1 | 2012-04-13 | 2015-01-18 | 2 - 9 - 6   |   132 |    471 | 2015-01-19 | 2015-01-30 |          12 | No               |        |         |     459 |             0 |
|      6 |     1 | 2015-01-31 | 2016-01-18 | 0 - 11 - 19 |    46 |    505 | 2016-01-19 | 2016-01-29 |          11 | No               |        |         |     494 |             0 |
|      7 |     1 | 2016-01-30 | 2017-04-04 | 1 - 2 - 6   |    56 |    550 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | No               |        |         |     550 |             0 |
|      8 |     1 | 2018-01-24 | 2018-07-07 | 0 - 5 - 14  |     5 |    555 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | Yes              |        |         |     555 |            31 |
|      9 |     1 | 2018-07-08 | 2018-07-15 | 0 - 0 - 8   |     0 |    555 | 1900-01-01 | 1900-01-01 |           0 | Yes              |        |         |     555 |            39 |
+--------+-------+------------+------------+-------------+-------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+------------------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+
```

RemainingDays :-

```
USE [Leave_Account]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[RemainingDays]    Script Date: 14-Dec-18 10:12:40 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RemainingDays]
(
   @FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME, @SummerVac nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT, @tmpFromDate DATETIME
    SET @Years = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, @FromDate, @ToDate),
          @FromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @Years , @FromDate)
    SET @Months =  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
              @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

    SET @tmpFromDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @Months , @tmpFromDate)
    SET @Days =  (DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate)
     - (CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @tmpFromDate, @ToDate),
              @tmpFromDate) > @ToDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+1)

    RETURN 
           Case when @SummerVac = 'Yes'
           then
            @DAYS 
           End
END
```

Comment: 1. DutyPeriod is (Years - Months - Days) between DutyFrom & DutyTo.
2. LeavesTaken is difference between LeaveTo and LeaveFrom

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```
RETURN 
       Case when @SummerVac = 'Yes' and @DAYS < 30 then @DAYS 
            when @SummerVac = 'Yes' and @DAYS >= 30 then (@DAYS - 30)
       End
```

---

Seems that all you need is a case expression:

> ```
> with cte as (
>      /* replace with your existing query */
>     select * 
>     from temp
>     )
> select
>      RemainingDays
>
>    , case when RemainingDays > 30 then RemainingDays - 30 
>           else RemainingDays
>      end as desired_rem_days
>
>    , FooSno,EmpNo,DutyFrom,DutyTo
> from cte
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> RemainingDays | desired_rem_days | FooSno | EmpNo | DutyFrom            | DutyTo             
> ------------: | ---------------: | -----: | ----: | :------------------ | :------------------
>             2 |                2 |      1 |     1 | 31/03/1997 00:00:00 | 01/07/2004 00:00:00
>             6 |                6 |      2 |     1 | 28/01/2006 00:00:00 | 31/12/2006 00:00:00
>             0 |                0 |      3 |     1 | 01/01/2007 00:00:00 | 23/03/2012 00:00:00
>            17 |               17 |      4 |     1 | 02/04/2012 00:00:00 | 12/04/2012 00:00:00
>             0 |                0 |      5 |     1 | 13/04/2012 00:00:00 | 18/01/2015 00:00:00
>             0 |                0 |      6 |     1 | 31/01/2015 00:00:00 | 18/01/2016 00:00:00
>             0 |                0 |      7 |     1 | 30/01/2016 00:00:00 | 04/04/2017 00:00:00
>            31 |                1 |      8 |     1 | 24/01/2018 00:00:00 | 07/07/2018 00:00:00
>            39 |                9 |      9 |     1 | 08/07/2018 00:00:00 | 15/07/2018 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=55d1658a67c6387f768f01ec55f6e261)*

Comment: What I want to do is that whenever RemainingDays Reaches to >= 30 then RemainingDays - 30 and (for e.g. RemainingDays =  31 then Result will be 1 as per 31-30) and the next RemainingDays will be calculated as {(Previous Value of) RemainingDays + (Current Value of)Days}

Comment: How can I  know how the next remaingdays is calculated? It is calculated by a function. The code to that function is not provided. I think you should take some time to consider how hard it is to answer any technical question and that we are volunteers. I have already devoted significant volunteer time to this question. Now it has a new dimension and I cannot rewrite your function.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and literally sorry for not clearing my view.
I've updated code for "RemainingDays" in code.

Comment: So there is a case expression at the end of that function, use that to return (@days - 30) when @days is > 30 .... is this what you need?

Comment: Dear friend, the problem has been resolved, Thank you very much for helping me.